# Adding view from Xib to a transparent view, why it shows darker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, alpha-transparency

Here is code

```
self.viewD = DayViewCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: 
self.containerView.frame.size.height))
```

this is opaque is false and background is clear.

```
self.viewD.isOpaque = false
self.viewD.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.containerView.addSubview(self.viewD)
```

Also for container same

```
container.isOpaque = false
container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

**Output :**

[image: In this image below the next text part of image showing slightly darker]

**if i don't add ViewD than container is transparent, as in image**

[image: image without viewD]

**Question**

Why Tow Transparent UIViews are not Transparent, it show slightly darker

Please suggest me where I am doing mistake

Comment: Is DayViewCalendar a class of yours ?

Comment: @claude31yes it is UIView xib class name.

Comment: can you paste here , your DayViewCalendar class ?

Comment: In particular, the draw() of DayViewCalendar

Comment: @claude31 there is nothing in draw()

Comment: So, please, could you post the complete DayViewCalendar

Answer (score 0):

Here is something which could help you in the long run.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

This could help you debug view components and tell you which view exactly is the causing the gray area in your UI.

Hope this helps. Happy debugging